# understanding regexp with array notation

Tags: ruby

I've met this code snippet:

```
erb = "#coding:UTF-8 _erbout = ''; _erbout.concat ..." # string is cut
erb[/\A(#coding[:=].*\r?\n)/, 1]
```

I know how regular expression works, but I am confused with the array notation. What does it mean to place a regexp in `[]`, what does the second argument `1` mean?

Comment: To complement the answers already given below, `String#[regex_or_string]` is like a 'filter' that passes only the part of the original string that matches `regex_or_string`. Without the second parameter, it passes the whole match. With the second paramter `1`, `2`, ..., it passes a particular capture `$1`, `$2`, ..., (that is, the first parenthesized part, second parenthesized part, ...) within the match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str[regexp]` is actually a method of class String, you can find it here http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001128

The second argument `1` will return text matching the first subpattern `#coding[:=].*\r?\n`, another example for your better understanding:

```
"ab123baab"[/(\d+)(ba+).*/, 0] # returns "123baab", since it is the complete matched text, ,0 can be omitted also
"ab123baab"[/(\d+)(ba+).*/, 1] # returns "123", since the first subpattern is (\d+)
"ab123baab"[/(\d+)(ba+).*/, 2] # returns "baa", since the second subpattern is (ba+)
```

Comment: You don't need the second parameter for the first line of your code. But if you still want to put it, it should be `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The brackets are a method of String. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html:

> If a Regexp is supplied, the matching
>   portion of str is returned. If a
>   numeric or name parameter follows the
>   regular expression, that component of
>   the MatchData is returned instead. If
>   a String is given, that string is
>   returned if it occurs in str. In both
>   cases, nil is returned if there is no
>   match.

The *1* means to return what's matched by the pattern inside the parenthesis.